# Update stock following Batch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I design a new application.
I use sQL server. So i have a prolem.
I want table tbStock caculate, in column tbStock.quality = tbImport.quality - tbExport.quality
but they have to follow field batch.
And this is my code. Not working

```
    create proc [dbo].[sp_XuatLayBatch]
    @Ma as nchar(14)

    as
    select sum(tbImport .SoLuong)as SLN,sum(tbExport .SoLuong)as SLX,tbImport .Batch from tbImport, tbExport
    where tbImport .Ma = @Ma and (tbExport.Ma=tbImport .Ma or tbExport.Ma is null)
    group by tbImport .Batch
```

this is my picture.
http://www.mediafire.com/view/l5fyiaa8flolgda/Batch_tong_2.JPG

Comment: That SP just select some sums, what exactly you need to achieve?

Comment: What you want to do ? What is connection between Sp and Formula for quality you have define ?

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I want  is the same: tbStock.quality = tbImport.quality - tbExport.quality.  The tbStock.quality Base on Batch in the table tbImport. As you see. The QUALITY, At the first record IS in the table Stock = the first record IS in the table tbImport - (the first record IS in the table tbExport + the second record IS in the table tbExport). So it mean, (tbStock.quality) : 0 = 500-(420

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are after: just a total of the exported stock subtracted from the amount of stock that was imported in that particular batch, to give you the overall stock remaining from that batch?

If so:

```
select i.[No]
        ,i.Code
        ,i.Name
        ,i.Quality - isnull(e.Quality,0) as Quality
        ,i.Batch
from tbImport i
    left join (select Code
                        ,Name
                        ,sum(Quality) as Quality
                        ,Batch
                from tbExport
                group by Code
                        ,Name
                        ,Batch
                ) e
        on(i.Code = e.Code
            and i.Name = e.Name
            and i.Batch = e.Batch
            )
 where i.Quality - isnull(e.Quality,0) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Example, i only want to get the value of Quality that ">0". How i can do it? Please help me. When i add the code into below the code it is not working. Where i.quality > e.Quality. select i.[No] ,i.Code ,i.Name ,i.Quality - isnull(e.Quality,0) as Quality ,i.Batch from tbImport i left join (select Code ,Name ,sum(Quality) as Quality ,Batch from tbExport group by Code ,Name ,Batch ) e on(i.Code = e.Code and i.Name = e.Name and i.Batch = e.Batch )Where Quality > 0.

Comment: @LaVanHai  You really need to do some research on SQL basics before proceeding with this project of yours.  Answer amended.